# Count cells in a column between repeated value to find the family size

Tags: find

Have Family data in excel as shown in image. Have to Find out Family size.
Please Suggest the formula.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrMCQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put `=IF(B2="Self",1,D1+1)`  in D2, drag downwards.

since the result is there.. we 'pull it up' by :

Put `=IF(OR(D3=1,D3=""),D2,E3)` in E2, and drag downwards.

now, we 'put it' in column C by :

Put `=IF(B2="self",E2,"")` in C2, drag again.

Please share if it works/not.